# How do I inject Jersey beans into Quartz job in Weld?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jersey, quartz-scheduler, jboss-weld

I have a pure JAX-RS application both in Glassfish and in jetty-servlet. I'm trying to inject some beans into Quartz job.

I've annotated Job fields with `@javax.inject.Inject`, but I also believe I need to make Job factory available to container, or vice versa - I'm somewhat lost here what end to start with.

How do I accomplish it?

Comment: Victor are do you want to @Inject jobs into your other beans?

Comment: No, the other way around. I basically need a logger and a DAO in a job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Victor without some more detail regarding your application I am going to assume you're running in a servlet container. There is no way to do it using a "pure" JAX-RS application.

However I would recommend you use CDI (Weld or OpenWebBeans). You can then use Deltaspike to enable the request context inside your Quartz job get a reference to a request scoped bean.

Enabling Weld in your servlet container is quite [simple](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.1.0.Final/en-US/html/environments.html#d0e5221)

A guide on enabling the request context outside of an HTTP request is available [here](http://struberg.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/controlling-cdi-containers-in-se-and-ee/)

By default you cannot inject @RequestScoped beans into your quartz job (there is no HTTP request hence no request context). To work around this you can either enable the request context by following the link above OR (and probably my approach) inject @Dependent scoped beans (which do the work) into your JAX RS beans (essentially wrappers), you can then easily get references to the @Dependent scoped beans inside your quartz job.

Here is my [web.xml](https://gist.github.com/2767693) and [pom.xml](https://gist.github.com/2769823) for running Weld and Jersey inside jetty, you will need jetty-plus, jetty-jndi and Weld dependencies.

Here is some [info](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/JNDI) about getting JNDI setup within jetty, however I do not use this method as I start jetty as an embedded container within a SE application, here is a code snippet of what I do:

```
String[] configurationClasses =
{
    "org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration",
    "org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration",
    "org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration",
    "org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration",
    "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration",
    "org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration"
};
WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
webapp.setConfigurationClasses(configurationClasses);
webapp.setDescriptor("/path/to/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml");
webapp.setContextPath("/");
webapp.setResourceBase("/path/to/webapp");
webapp.setClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
```

Comment: Sorry for being wildly unspecific. I'm using Weld, I believe, in `jetty-servlet`. Updating the question now.

Comment: Can you please also share your `pom.xml`?

Comment: Thanks. Very similar configuration fails to start for me with: `IllegalStateException: Nothing to bind for name javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager/default at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusDescriptorProcessor.bindEntry(PlusDescriptorProcessor.java:890)`. Can you please give me a hand why?

Comment: @VictorSergienko i've included what I do to enable jndi within jetty, i;ve been meaning to blog about getting jersey, weld, jsf2 & jetty all playing nice from within a j2se application so i will try do that on the weekend and will stick a sample project of it in github as well.

Comment: Thanks for DeltaSpike again, this is the main part I was missing. Sadly I didn't have the luxury of creating Context myself.

Comment: may I also ask you to take a look at my new question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127665/jettyjersey-servletweld-weld-injection-not-initialized-what-is-wrong