# Jetty+Jersey servlet+Weld: Weld injection not initialized, what is wrong?

Tags: java, jetty, jersey, jboss-weld

I'm trying to migrate from Glassfish+Jersey+Weld to Jetty.

I have such a setup: [gist of pom.xml, web.xml and Java launcher](https://gist.github.com/2961967).

Application seems to start fine, but when serving any request I see that the field that should be injected by Weld (`logger`) is null.

```
@RequestScoped
@Path("/foobar")
@Consumes({ ExtendedMediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, 
    ExtendedMediaType.APPLICATION_JAVASCRIPT })
@Produces({ ExtendedMediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, 
    ExtendedMediaType.APPLICATION_JAVASCRIPT })
public class EmailResource extends {

    @Inject
    private Logger logger;

    @Override @POST
    public Response create(EmailJob document) 
        throws URISyntaxException, ResourceException 
    {
       logger.debug("Hi there!");
    }
}
```

What is the problem?

**update:** Logger producer looks dubious, but it doesn't even get called:

```
/** This class uses CDI to alias Java EE resources into CDI beans. **/
public class Resources {

    @Produces
    public Logger produceLog(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        return LoggerFactory.getLogger(
            injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi Victor my answer as requested, I've [blogged](http://www.lifeasageek.com/2012/06/java-ee-6-web-profile-without-app.html) about this with embedded jetty. I've also pushed a fully working example to [github](https://github.com/justinwyer/goodstuff-example/tree/part2) that you can clone.

I don't see anything wrong in your gist, however could you show your Logger producer?

UPDATE:

I see a typo "BeanMnanager" in your code, but not sure if it is the cause

```
new Resource("BeanManager", new Reference("javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanMnanager",
        "org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory", null));
```

Comment: I just wonder why is `AppServlet` in part2. Shouldn't it work with Jersey servlet only? That doesn't look too clean.

Comment: BTW you cau use `com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages` and go without `RestConfig.getClasses()`.

Comment: @VictorSergienko AppServlet is just to show off a CDI entry point after Jetty startup incase you want to do any post boot configuration or something, it is not required at all. As for the RestConfig not to sure...